# Create or update record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to check by an unique ID whether a record is already created. If it is, I want to add 1 to the amount attribute. If it is not, I want to create it and set the amount attribute to 1.

I already have this: `#@have = current_user.haves.create_or_update_by_id(params[:have])` but I'm not quite sure how I would set the amount right.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use ActiveRecord's `increment` method ([Documentation](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Persistence/increment)):

```
@have = current_user.haves.find_or_initialize_by_id(params[:have])
@have.increment(:amount)
@have.save
```

It initializes amount attribute to zero if nil and adds the value passed as by (default is 1). If not nil, it just increment the attribute value.

Answer (score 1):

I would probably split this into two operations.

```
@have = current_user.haves.find_or_initialize_by_id(params[:have]) do |h|
  h.amount = 0
end

@have.amount += 1
@have.save
```

The first statemnt will find the record by its unique ID or initialize a new record with the provided ID and amount set to 0. The block is only run on initialize, not on find. Then we increment the amount no matter what the state was originally and save the record back to the db.

Comment: That do end block only executes if the record is being initialized, but will not execute if the record is found?